# How to fix 'invalid set index position on base kinematic body' error in Godot?

Tags: godot, gdscript

In Godot i'm trying to get a kinematic body to teleport to the position of the mouse and i get this error: `Invalid set index 'position' (on base: 'KinematicBody') with value of type 'Vector3'.`I don't want to use move and slide as I want the item to be teleported to the mouse, not move towards the mouse

My code:

```py
extends KinematicBody

# Declare member variables here. Examples:
# var a = 2
# var b = "text"

# Called when the node enters the scene tree for the first time.
func _ready():
    pass # Replace with function body.

# Called every frame. 'delta' is the elapsed time since the previous frame.
func _process(delta):
    if (Input.is_action_pressed("ui_right")):
        rotate_y(-0.1)
    elif (Input.is_action_pressed("ui_left")):
        rotate_y(0.1)
    elif (Input.is_action_pressed("ui_up")):
        rotate_z(0.1)
    elif (Input.is_action_pressed("ui_down")):
        rotate_z(-0.1)
    var tempPosition = place()
    print(tempPosition)
    if tempPosition != null:
        var temp_mesh  =get_tree().get_root().get_node("World/TestBody")
        temp_mesh.position = tempPosition


func _input(event):
    if event is InputEventMouseMotion:
        rotate_y(-event.relative.x * 0.0002)
        $pivot.rotate_x(-event.relative.y * 0.0002)
        $pivot.rotation.x = clamp($pivot.rotation.x, -1.2, 1.2)

# Place an item
func place():
    var ray_length = 5000
    var mouse_pos = get_viewport().get_mouse_position()
    var camera = get_node("pivot/Camera")
    var from = camera.project_ray_origin(mouse_pos)
    var to = from + camera.project_ray_normal(mouse_pos) * ray_length
    var space_state = get_world().get_direct_space_state()
    var result = space_state.intersect_ray(from, to)
    if result:
        return result.position
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`KinematicBody` does not have a `position` property (only `KinematicBody2D` does). For 3D [`Spatial`](https://godot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/classes/class_spatial.html#spatial) objects like `KinematicBody`, you should use `global_transform.origin`.

Comment: When i use this method my object moves according to the mouse, but does not go to the mouse.

Comment: Fixed it! My kinematic body was on a offset to the mesh!